# how to turn disabled button into enabled button depending on conditions

Tags: button, flutter, textfield, txtextcontrol

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to make a button disabled as long as some text fields are empty, so i made 3 textcontrollers to act as a controller for the 3 text fields and i made a function to check the function is:

```
bool isEmpty(){
    setState(() {
          if(textEditingController.text!=" "&&textEditingController2.text!=" "&& textEditingController3.text!=" "){
            isButtonEnabled=true;


          }
        });
       return isButtonEnabled; 
  }
```

And the code for the text field is:

```
TextField(
                  onSubmitted:null,

                  controller: textEditingController3,


                )
```

Then i write the code for the button as follows:
  Center(

```
  child: RaisedButton(
         child: Text("Button 1",style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),),
          onPressed:isButtonEnabled?(){ print("enabled");}:null,
          color: Colors.red,

            ),
```

The problem is the button remains disabled even after i write in the text fields. Any idea?
Thanks in advance.
**EDIT:**
 thanks to @diegoveloper answer this worked, but what if i wanted to put intital value and i want the button to be enabled only if the text fields have values for the text fields as following :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   textEditingController  = new TextEditingController(text: name);
      textEditingController2  = new TextEditingController(text: email);
         textEditingController3  = new TextEditingController(text: " place");


  }
```

Then i updated the isEmpty method to be:

```
bool isEmpty(){
    setState(() {
          if((textEditingController.text!=" ")&&(textEditingController2.text!=" ")&& (textEditingController3.text!=" ")&&(textEditingController!=null)&&(textEditingController2!=null)&&(textEditingController3!=null)){
            isButtonEnabled=true;



          }
          else{
                        isButtonEnabled=false;

          }
        });
       return isButtonEnabled; 
  }
```

The problem is despite of the intials values i gave to text fields the button is still disabled, also when i edit the 3 values of textfields the button is enabled, but if i deleted the text (in which i think it's meant by null) the button is still disabled.

Comment: when do you call "isEmpty" method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read more about TextField here: https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes/

So you have two options :

1 - Listen for changes on each `TextEditingController` and call to your method `isEmpty()`

2 - Add the `onChanged` callback on each `TextField` you want to listen the changes.

**Option 2**

```
TextField(
  onSubmitted: null,
  onChanged: (val) {
    isEmpty();
  },
  controller: textEditingController3,
)
```

Note: don't forget to add the ELSE condition to your isEmpty method.

**Edit**

Modify your initState method to check if your button is enable (refactor this code please)

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: "name");
    textEditingController2 = TextEditingController(text: "email");
    textEditingController3 = TextEditingController(text: "place");

    if ((textEditingController.text.trim() != "") && (textEditingController2.text.trim() != "") && (textEditingController3.text.trim() != "")) {
        isButtonEnabled = true;
    } else {
        isButtonEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this worked for the first time i write in the text field, but when i delete the text i put space in the text field again it did not turn in to disabled i don't know why?

Comment: Could you update your question with your latest code? I see that you have 3 texteditingcontroller

Comment: Oh wait, in your isEmpty method you have an if condition add and ELSE and set isButtonEnabled false

Comment: Thank you this worked, could you please check the edit? i have another problem

Comment: I don't understand your question , what do you need?

Comment: change your conditions  text != ""   <===  not  text!= " "  <== blank space

Comment: I need to put initial value for my text fields, and i already did in the initState, so i expect that the button has to be enabled as the textfield is not have spaces or empty it turns into enabled only if i pressed on one of them as if i edit them,  also i want to check if the text field is empty i would like to make the the button disabled also if it is empty, but the case here is when i delete all the text of any of the textfields the button does not turn into disabled

Comment: that's because your condition is wrong   text != ""  is ok , not text != " "

Comment: or you could try : text.trim() != ""

Comment: and on your initState use the same conditions but you can not use setState there. 

if (...your conditions )  {
   isButtonEnabled = true;
} else {
   isButtonEnabled = false;
 }  

but don't use setState, you'll have to refactor your code

Comment: Yes! i thought "" will equal to null, thank you for your help, but the only problem left is that's when i put initial values for the controller i expected the button to be enabled because the text is neither blank or space but the button appear initially disabled?!

Answer (score 20):

You don't need any additional libraries to do that. Flutter has it out-of-the-box and you can make sure you're not going to rebuild the whole tree on each keystroke.

`TextEditingController` extends `ValueNotifier<TextEditingValue>` which means you can utilize `ValueListenableBuilder` from `material` package to listen to text changes.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _inputController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _inputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      TextField(controller: _inputController),
      ValueListenableBuilder<TextEditingValue>(
        valueListenable: _inputController,
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: value.text.isNotEmpty ? () {} : null,
            child: Text('I am disabled when text is empty'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is so helpful, simple and very clean, plus you dont have to rebuild your widget tree on each keystroke indeed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested [TextEditingWatcher](https://pub.dev/packages/text_editing_watcher)s

Comment: Perfect. Just what I need.